# Add button will trigger when same details

Tags: visual-foxpro

```
SELECT series   
APPEND BLANK
    Replace doc_num WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.docnum.value
    Replace doc_type WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.doctype.value
    Replace doc_title WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.doctitle.value
    Replace doc_date WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.docdate.value
    Replace rec_date WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.recdate.value
    Replace pub_date WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.pubdate.value
    Replace sector WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.sector.value
    Replace cluster WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.cluster.value
    Replace reg_office WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.region.value
    Replace revision WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.revision.value
    Replace processedby WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.procby.value
    Replace reviewedby WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.revby.value
    Replace encodedby WITH thisform.pageframe1.page1.encby.value
            MESSAGEBOX("New record successfully saved...",0+64,"Success")
```

This is my code in my add button, can you please help me what's next when i add same info it will trigger that details was already save. thanks.

Comment: Check insert-sql command in help. This is a dangerous way to insert new records (record is not locked in between the commands and in a multiuser environment it is possible to create a situation where different users are updating the same record in fact). Insert is a single command to do this all in one step.

Comment: Could you explain what you are needing help with more?

Answer (score 0):

As per Cetin Basoz the command should be

```
INSERT INTO series ( doc_num, doc_type, doc_title, doc_date, ;
rec_date, pub_date, sector, cluster, reg_office, revision, processedby, ;
reviewedby, encodedby) VALUES ;
(thisform.pageframe1.page1.docnum.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.doctype.value
thisform.pageframe1.page1.doctitle.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.docdate.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.recdate.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.pubdate.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.sector.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.cluster.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.region.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.revision.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.procby.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.revby.value, ;
thisform.pageframe1.page1.encby.value)
MESSAGEBOX("New record successfully saved...",0+64,"Success")
```

You can set primary key if table series is not free and connected to a database. if not then you can use command like

```
select series
locate for doc_num = thisform.pageframe1.page1.docnum.value or ;
doc_type = thisform.pageframe1.page1.doctype.value or ; ...... and so on
if found()
*here what to do if data found in table
endif
```